# how to updating scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to update classRollNum value but when printing on console its for refleting. What wrong I am doing here >

```
function classRollNumCtrl($scope, studentList, Restangular) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.studentList = studentList.plain();

        vm.updateRollNum = function () {
            for (var x in vm.studentList) {
                console.log("x --> " + x)
                vm.studentList.classRollNum= x+1;  // UPDATEING VALUE
            }

            console.log("vm.studentList --> " + JSON.stringify(vm.studentList));
        }
    }

}());
```

My vm.studentList looks like this.

```
vm.studentList = [
                {"studentName":"Abhinav  Chandel","classRollNum":null},
                {"studentName":"Achin  Agarwal","classRollNum":null},
                {"studentName":"Amartya  Khan","classRollNum":null}
                ]
```

Comment: Confused on what you're doing. Why not declare `vm.studentList = [...` inside your controller?

Comment: @LJ.Wizard : corrected above. vm.studentList is my resolve of studentList. I am surprise why vm.studentList.classNumRoll = x+1;  is not update value

Comment: Because `classNumRoll` != `classRollNum`

Comment: @dex: Still not working ... I corrected that typo

Comment: In addition, you need to use `vm.studentList[x].classNumRoll` to edit an entry (and not the whole array)

Comment: post your view code.

Comment: @dex You are correct ... resolved. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
x.classRollNum = x.classRollNum +1;
```

or by check null

```
x.classRollNum = x.classRollNum ? x.classRollNum +1 : 1;
```

instead of

```
vm.studentList.classNumRoll = x+1;
```

Also typo. in list has `classRollNum` but used `classNumRoll` and `studentList` is an array so you can't use `studentList.classRollNum` you can use in for loop like `x.classRollNum` or `studentList[0].classRollNum`